# How Count words and lines with x number of vowels C# multi-line textbox Windows form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

So far I am able to count only the number of vowels, but not per word.  I can also count the number of lines with only one word.  What I really need help with is counting words with only a certain number of vowels.  I also need to be able to count the lines with a certain number of vowels too.  Here is my code so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string word = textBox1.Text;

    int count = 0;
    // int vowelCount = 0;
    foreach (char vowel in word)
    {
        if (vowel == 'a' || vowel == 'A' || vowel == 'e' || vowel == 'E' || vowel == 'i' || vowel == 'I' || vowel == 'o' || vowel == 'O' || vowel == 'u' || vowel == 'U')
        {
            count++;

        }


    } 

    int lineCount = 0;
    LineCountlbl.Text = lineCount.ToString();
    LineCountlbl.Text = word.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString();
}
```

Looking for words with 3 vowels or more, every two lines
Intended output:

1. indivisible, with liberty and justice for all, should be rendered
2. by standing at **attention** facing the flag with the right hand over
3. the heart. When not in uniform men should remove any non-religious
4. **headdress** with their right hand and hold it at the left **shoulder**.

Word Vowel Count: 3  Lines: 2

Comment: From your code, we can see you already know how to use `Split`. So `Split` your input into lines, then loop and `Split` each line by white space to give you words, then count the vowels in each word. You question isn't entirely clear on what you actually want as output.

Comment: Who would mark my question down a point?!  I actually need the help.  So mean on here.

Comment: @GreenArrow: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @GreenArrow, don't take downvotes as personal attacks or proof that someone thinks you don't need help.  Upvotes and downvotes are about the quality and relevance of the question, not about whether you need help or whether people like you.

Comment: @MattBurland  I need a visual.  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Given a string `input`, you could use `String.Split` as follows to separate it into individual words.

```
var Words
  = input.Split(new char[] { Environment.EndLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Proceeding further, you could use Linq as follows to map an individual string to its number of vowels.

```
var Vowels = "aeiou";
Func<string,int> NumOfVowels
    = iString => iString.ToLower().Count( iChar => Vowels.Contains( iChar ) );
var NumberOfVowelsPerWord = input.Select( NumOfVowels );
```

If finally `n` is a given number of vowels, the number of words in `input` with exactly `n` vowels can be obtained as follows.

```
int Count = input.Select( NumOfVowels ).Count( iInt => iInt == n );
```

Comment: You also need to account for upper case vowels. A simple `ToLower` would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @MattBurland Thanks for the comment, I edited in your suggestion.

Comment: @Codor thank you so much for the example.  I am gonna try it out and see which one helps best!  Thank you for being kind!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example, with detailed comments inside of my code.

```
var myText = new []
{
    "My name is Orel Eraki and i love snooker",
    "I also enjoy Hiking and visiting different cultures."
};

const string vowels = "aeiou";
int minVowelsPerLine = 3;
int minVowelsPerWord = 2;
int numberOfLinesWithMoreThanXVowels = 0;
foreach (var line in myText)
{
    // Lowering entire line, to simplify the equality check.
    string workingLine = line.ToLower();
    // Splitting words into array for working on each word in array separately.
    var wordsInALine = workingLine.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // Counting the characters on each word if they appears(contains) in the 'vowels' array
    // and eventually seeing if the number of each 'vowles' in word is at least 'minVowelsPerWord' amount.
    int numberOfWordsWithAtLeastXVowels = wordsInALine.Count(word => word.ToLower().Count(c => vowels.Contains(c)) > minVowelsPerWord);
    // Counting the entire 'vowles' inside a line.
    int numberOfVowlesInLine = workingLine.Count(c => vowels.Contains(c));

    if (numberOfVowlesInLine > minVowelsPerLine)
    {
        numberOfLinesWithMoreThanXVowels++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Line[{0}] has {1} words with at least {2} vowles in them.", line, numberOfLinesWithMoreThanXVowels, minVowelsPerWord);
}
Console.WriteLine("Text has {0} lines with at least {1} vowles in them.", numberOfLinesWithMoreThanXVowels, minVowelsPerLine);
```

Comment: Thank you @OrelEraki.  I am gonna try it out in the Windows Form

Comment: I really don't have an idea, why this was downvoted. GreenArrow, did it helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's say we have some text:

```
string input = "here is some text\nthat breaks over\nmultiple lines\nand we are going\nto count the vowels";
```

The first thing we need to do is split it into lines:

```
var lines = input.Split('\n');
```

Now `lines` is an array of lines.

Now we'll loop through each line and for each line we'll get the number of words:

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    // Get words
    var words = line.Split(' ');
    // ...
}
```

We are assuming there aren't multiple spaces between words, but it's not that difficult to deal with if that becomes an issue (you could use `Regex.Split` for example).

Now inside this loop, you can loop the `words` and test each word. There are several ways to count them, I'm going to use a regex:

```
var vowels = var vowels = new Regex("[aeiou]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    // Get words
    var words = line.Split(' ');
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        var vowelCount = vowels.Matches(word).Count;
    }
}
```

There are, of course, much more compact ways to do this with LINQ, but this should give you the basic outline of how to think about the problem. Once you have the number of vowels for each word, you can do whatever it is you need, count words with only a certain number of vowels, or count lines with a certain total number of vowels, or whatever you need to do (your question isn't entirely clear on what you really need for output here).

**Edit**: So based on the now edited question, you could do something like:

```
var vowels = var vowels = new Regex("[aeiou]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var lineCount = 0;
var wordCount = 0;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    bool hasThreeVowelWord = false;
    // Get words
    var words = line.Split(' ');
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        var vowelCount = vowels.Matches(word).Count;
        if (vowelCount == 3)
        {
            wordCount++; 
            hasThreeVowelWord = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasThreeVowelWord) { lineCount++; }
}
```

Now `lineCount` is the number of lines containing at least one word with three vowels, and `wordCount` is the number of words with three vowels.

Comment: The output should be.  Only count the words with 3 vowels and only every 2 lines.  Let me write it in the question.

Comment: It literally counts each vowel per word, but not a tally of the vowels.